# Waiting for package manager lock

Tags: update-manager

Today I installed Elementary OS 5.1.7 and tried to run the update. Unfortunately, updates cannot be performed. Each time, it hangs on the Waiting for package manager lock message and puts the update at the end of the list.

Can this problem be fixed?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This can sometimes happen but, fortunately, it’s not a common occurrence? It can generally be resolved like this:

1. Open Terminal
2. Run this command:

   ```
   sudo dpkg --configure -a
   ```

Once this completes, you should be able to update normally.

Comment: Thanks for this, fixed the problem for me. For those who are less comfortable just copy-pasting commands, here is what that means: https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=sudo+dpkg+--configure+-a